# GameKit: Connection to plugin interrupted while in use

Tags: swift, gamekit

I have been trying to solve the issue for a few weeks already. No response on the Apple Developers forum. No real help from the Apple Developer Technical Support. Given a high probability of the issue occurring in my project, I cannot believe it has not been addressed by anyone. Anyways, this is my GameKitManager class:

```
final class GameCenterManager : NSObject, GKLocalPlayerListener {
    
    static let manager = GameCenterManager()
    weak var delegate: GameCenterManagerDelegate?
    var gameCenterViewController: UIViewController?
    var match: GKMatch?
    static var isAuthenticated: Bool {
        return GKLocalPlayer.local.isAuthenticated
    }
    var matchmakerViewController: GKMatchmakerViewController?
    var invite: GKInvite?
    
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func authenticatePlayer() {

        GKLocalPlayer.local.authenticateHandler = { gcAuthVC, error in
            
            self.delegate?.didChangeAuthStatus(isAuthenticated: GKLocalPlayer.local.isAuthenticated)

            if GKLocalPlayer.local.isAuthenticated {
                GKLocalPlayer.local.register(self)
            }
            // If the User needs to sign to the Game Center
            else if let vc = gcAuthVC {
                self.delegate?.presentGameCenterAuth(viewController: vc)
            }
            else {
                print(">>>>> Error authenticating the Player! \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "none") <<<<<")
            }
        }
    }
    

    func presentMatchmaker() {
        guard GKLocalPlayer.local.isAuthenticated else { return }
        
        let request = GKMatchRequest()
        request.minPlayers = 2
        request.maxPlayers = 4
        request.inviteMessage = "Would you like to play?"
        
        matchmakerViewController = GKMatchmakerViewController(matchRequest: request)
        matchmakerViewController!.matchmakerDelegate = self
        delegate?.presentMatchmaking(viewController: matchmakerViewController)
    }
    
    
    func player(_ player: GKPlayer, didAccept invite: GKInvite) {
        self.invite = invite
        // Start match making 4 seconds after to let the invitation sliding menu to finish loading
        let seconds = 4.0
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
            self.makeMatchmakerVC(from: invite)
        }
    }
    
    
    func makeMatchmakerVC(from invite:GKInvite) {
        // Accepting invitation from GKMatchmakerViewController (Friends are displayed)
        if matchmakerViewController != nil {
            matchmakerViewController!.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                self.matchmakerViewController = GKMatchmakerViewController(invite: invite)
                self.matchmakerViewController!.matchmakerDelegate = self
                self.delegate?.presentMatchmaking(viewController: self.matchmakerViewController!)
            })
        }
        // Accepting invitation when GKMatchmakerViewController is not yet presented
        else {
            guard let vc = GKMatchmakerViewController(invite: invite) else { return }
            self.matchmakerViewController = vc
            matchmakerViewController!.matchmakerDelegate = self
            delegate?.presentMatchmaking(viewController: matchmakerViewController!)
        }
    }
}


extension GameCenterManager: GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate {
    
    func matchmakerViewController(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController, didFind match: GKMatch) {
        
        print("-----matchmakerVC did find match-------")
        
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            self.match = match
            self.match!.delegate = self
            self.delegate?.presentGame(match: self.match!)
        })
    }
    

    func matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController) {
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true)
        delegate?.matchmakingCancelled()
    }
    

    func matchmakerViewController(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController,
                                  didFailWithError error: Error)
    {
        
        viewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

            print("################# fail with error ##################\n\(error.localizedDescription)\n")
            self.matchmakerViewController!.matchmakerDelegate = nil
            self.matchmakerViewController = nil
            self.invite = nil
            self.match = nil
        })
    }
}
```

This is how to replicate the problem.

- Players start the app. Both see the Intro screen.
- Player 1 taps on  "Play in GameCenter". Matchmaker VC is open now for Player 1.
- Player 1 adds Player 2 to the game and taps on the Invite and Start button.
- Player 2 receives the invitation (sliding message from the top) and immediately taps on it to accept the invitation (do not wait for the invitation to finish playing the tune). Note that Player 2 is still in the Intro scene.
- Player 2 gets a connection error, even though he/she accepted the invitation, whereas Player 1 is notified that Player 2 joined the game and proceeds to the game scene.
- As far as the code flow is concerned, Player 2 calls method 'player(player: invite:)'; a new matchmakerViewController is created from the invite and becomes presented; while it is done, Player 2 receives the following error:

  -----player -- did accept invite-------player2

  ....INTROSCENE: DELEGATE PRESENT_MATCHMAKING CALLED......

  2020-11-08 17:03:07.083450-0500 igkTest[48868:2788074] [lifecycle] [u 196C65DD-6BC1-46D7-B43D-1399E5802378:m (null)] [com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterMatchmakerExtension(1.0)] Connection to plugin interrupted while in use.

  2020-11-08 17:03:07.083680-0500 igkTest[48868:2788073] [lifecycle] [u 196C65DD-6BC1-46D7-B43D-1399E5802378:m (null)] [com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterMatchmakerExtension(1.0)] Connection to plugin invalidated while in use.

  2020-11-08 17:03:07.160824-0500 igkTest[48868:2788043] [Match] cannot set connecting state for player: (playerID:G:271575631, alias:player), as there is no inviteDelegate set yet. The state might directly change to Ready when we set the inviteDelegate later and call sendQueuedStatesAndPackets.

  2020-11-08 17:03:07.166467-0500 igkTest[48868:2788074] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>

  2020-11-08 17:03:07.169507-0500 igkTest[48868:2788074] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>

  2020-11-08 17:03:07.170369-0500 igkTest[48868:2788070] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>

  2020-11-08 17:03:07.175163-0500 igkTest[48868:2788043] [Error] Extension request interrupted with error: Error Domain=ExtensionErrorDomain Code=-5900 "(null)"

  2020-11-08 17:03:07.218324-0500 igkTest[48868:2788043] viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}

  2020-11-08 17:03:07.652617-0500 igkTest[48868:2788043] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] VCCTServiceMonitor_GetDataIndicatorStatus:193 Device does not have cellular baseband

  2020-11-08 17:03:07.944964-0500 igkTest[48868:2788203] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] OSPFParse_ParsePacketHeader:1083 Bad destination count=0

  2020-11-08 17:03:07.946241-0500 igkTest[48868:2788203] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] OSPFParse_ParsePacketHeader:1100 Checksum=42050 doesn't match

  2020-11-08 17:03:07.965383-0500 igkTest[48868:2788223] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] gckSessionCheckPendingConnections:1454 gckSessionCheckPendingConnections: iICEChecksLeft=0, iUnconnectedNodeCount=0, iDDsExpected=1

  2020-11-08 17:03:07.966116-0500 igkTest[48868:2788223] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] ProcessEvent:1201    Send BINDING_REQUEST failed(801A0016).

  2020-11-08 17:03:07.967086-0500 igkTest[48868:2788074] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] ICEStopConnectivityCheck:2740 ICEStopConnectivityCheck() found no ICE check with call id (2014448547)

  2020-11-08 17:03:07.992298-0500 igkTest[48868:2788203] [ViceroyTrace]  [ERROR] gckSessionCheckPendingConnections:1454 gckSessionCheckPendingConnections: iICEChecksLeft=0, iUnconnectedNodeCount=0, iDDsExpected=0

  ################# fail with error ##################

  The operation couldn’t be completed. (ExtensionErrorDomain error -5900.)

Player 2 throws method 'matchmakerViewController( viewController: error:)', but since he/she already accepted the invitation Player 1 assumes that the invitation has been accepted and proceeds to the game with 'self.delegate?.presentGame(match: self.match!)'.

This does not happen every time, but every 2nd or 3rd time when Player 2 accepts invitation too early.

Thanks a lot in advance if anyone can help!

Comment: I have found another use case when the error occurs.

Player 1 invites Player 2 to play a game and Player 2 accepts the invitation. Then either Player stops the match (match is cancelled and is nil now for both: `GameCenterManager.manager.match.disconnect(); GameCenterManager.manager.match = nil`). Then, Player 2 invites Player 1, and Player 1 accepts the invitation to another match. Player 2 finds the match and goes to the Game Scene, whereas player 1 ends up with this error (accepts an invitation and then fails to create a new match).

Answer (score 1):

If someone is experiencing the same issue, would the following help?

```
func player(_ player: GKPlayer, didAccept invite: GKInvite) {
        if matchmakerViewController != nil {
            matchmakerViewController!.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
            self.matchmakerViewController!.matchmakerDelegate = nil
            self.matchmakerViewController = nil
        }

        let delayTime = DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(2000)

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delayTime) {
            self.matchmakerViewController = GKMatchmakerViewController(invite: invite)
            self.matchmakerViewController!.matchmakerDelegate = self
            self.delegate?.presentMatchmaking(viewController: self.matchmakerViewController!)
        }
}
```

The Dispatch.asyncAfter is giving the system time to do a full "clean-up" of matchmakerViewController before starting new task. I am testing it now but other people's feedback would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
After more testing, this did not prove to be the solution; the problem continued. However, I noticed that I do not have the issue when the second player has an instance of GKMatchmakerViewController open. In other words, if I call `presentMatchmaker()` first, and then accept an invitation, it works. So, the problem occurs when, for example, the second player is not in the game and receives an invitation to play. Thus, I changed my code to the following, which seems to be working so far:

```
public func player(_ player: GKPlayer, didAccept invite: GKInvite) {
        if matchmakerViewController != nil {
            matchmakerViewController!.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
            self.matchmakerViewController!.matchmakerDelegate = nil
            self.matchmakerViewController = nil
        }
        
        // THIS HELPS AVOID CRASH.
        presentMatchmaker()
        
        let delayTime = DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(1000)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delayTime) {
            self.matchmakerViewController = GKMatchmakerViewController(invite: invite)
            self.matchmakerViewController!.matchmakerDelegate = self
            self.delegate?.presentMatchmaking(viewController: self.matchmakerViewController!)
        }
    }
```

Not a very elegant solution...

Comment: If somebody else experiences this issue, I found that creating and displaying the `GKMatchmakerViewController` and then setting the delegate within a `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now())` also fixes the issue. This is still a hack but seems somewhat more clean because no additional view controller is needed and there's no delay.

Comment: Thanks. As you see in my last piece of code, this is what I do. Still have the same issue without calling `presentMatchmaker()`. Cheers.